# jQuery: Add Sibling of Parent to Current Matched Elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to - in one line - remove the parent element of a clicked element and the parent's lone sibling element. This is my two-liner solution here:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.close').click(function() {
        $(this).parent().siblings('.sibling').remove();
        $(this).parent().remove();
    });
});
```

[Here's a working fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/GYatesIII/5NCfN/) I'm looking to avoid navigating the DOM twice since I've already found the parent of the clicked element when I remove the sibling, there's no reason I should be doing it again. I'm aware that I could wrap both the parent and sibling in an element and just remove that super element, but at this point I'd like to avoid that as well.

I've looked into using jQuery's [`.add()`](http://api.jquery.com/add/) function, but I can't seem to get that to work. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for [`.addBack()`](http://api.jquery.com/addBack/):

```
$(this).parent().siblings('.sibling').addBack().remove();
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/5NCfN/1/)

- [`andSelf`](http://api.jquery.com/andSelf/) is an equivalent to `.addBack()` for jQuery < 1.8

---

With `.add()`, you would have to store the parent in a variable to avoid traversing to it twice:

```
var $father = $(this).parent();
$father.siblings('.sibling').add($father).remove();
//one-liner without storing in a variable would traverse the DOM twice:
$(this).parent().siblings('.sibling').add($(this).parent()).remove();
```

As you can see, the `addBack` method is more practical in this case.

In case the element's parent and the parent's sibling are the only elements inside their parent, you can also use:

```
$(this.parentNode.parentNode).empty();
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/5NCfN/2/)

The native `parentNode` property is a bit faster than jQuery's `.parent()` method. It is up to which to use.

---

Note that such small traversing has very little overhead either way. Your original code and these versions have very little difference performance-wise.

Comment: `addBack()` is exactly what I was looking for, and this question is a much simplified representative of my real problem which you just solved. Thanks for the detailed answer.